Getting profile badges (Discord.py)
I want to get the badges of a discord user using discord.py. I am currently using Python 3.12.6 and the latest version of discord.py. The method that I'm using right now is that I have a function that takes in a message object and takes the first mentioned user in that message and uses it as the user to fetch the info from. What I have right now is this:
user = message.mentions[0] # Gets the user from who to take the info from
badges  = user.public_flags # Gets the badges
badges_str = str(badges.all()).replace('[<UserFlags.', '').replace('>]', '').replace('_',' ').replace(':', '').title() # Replaces not needed info
badges_str = ''.join([i for i in badges_str if not i.isdigit()]) # removes the numbers

Now I have also tried to print all the values, including badges, but all of it just does not work. The user is on the guild that this command is being run on, and I have many exceptions to confirm that the user exists, and the program is fetching the correct person.
All that I really want is to get a list of badge Objects or strings  that I can link to icons to show the badges in a nice little embed. But all that I'm getting is an empty array instead. There is no information and I even tried it on other servers, roles, bots, tokens, intents, etc...
I tried to read the docs (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/) and I tried to look at many other stack overflow questions and look at other Python projects on GitHub that are doing this or something similar. All that, and down to reading the source code of discord.py. Nothing helped, and I am coming here to hopefully find an answer to a relatively weird question.

So when it returns an empty array, is it from the user.public_flags?

This question is similar to: Discord.py Showing User Badges. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

yeah for some reason

Are you referring to the duplicate question or the empty array

Well, I did a check, and now it's kind of working. It shows the regular badges, but the boost and nitro ones don't show up!

I think these might not be badges for the API but their own things where you can check for how long the user boosts servers etc via the API.

Are boost badges and nitro badges even provided by the API?

So user.public_flags.all() is actually a list of Enums. Rather than converting the whole list of enums to a string and stripping a bunch of extraneous stuff, you might find more success using it as the data it is, e.g.:
user = message.mentions[0]
badges = [badge.name for badge in user.public_flags.all()]


Well even after doing that it still returns an empty array! lol

Possible only a summary object is included and you might have to do user = client.get_user(message.mentions[0].user_id) instead? If that doesn't work, maybe you need the discord.Intents.member "intent" enabled?

it's now a weird sub-issue but your answer helped, not fully tho. check out the post comments

Can't respond to that one yet, but: it looks like Nitro/Boost aren't part of the UserFlags, just reading the docs. You might need Member.premium_since is not None (or scan Guild.premium_subscribers) to determine if they boosted the server. I don't see anything in the documentation about just checking if the user has Nitro.
